clarification for leetcode question (Alien Dictionary)
I am not asking for a solution, I simply need clarification
The question states:
"
There is a foreign language language which uses the latin alphabet, but the order among letters is not "a", "b", "c" ... "z" as in English.
You receive a list of non-empty strings words from the dictionary, where the words are sorted lexicographically based on the rules of this new language.
Derive the order of letters in this language. If the order is invalid, return an empty string. If there are multiple valid order of letters, return any of them.
A string a is lexicographically smaller than a string b if either of the following is true:
The first letter where they differ is smaller in a than in b.
There is no index i such that a[i] != b[i] and a.length < b.length.
"
The example given is
Input: ["hrn","hrf","er","enn","rfnn"]
Output: "hernf"
Explanation:
from "hrn" and "hrf", we know 'n' < 'f'
from "hrf" and "er", we know 'h' < 'e'
from "er" and "enn", we know get 'r' < 'n'
from "enn" and "rfnn" we know 'e'<'r'
Hence, one solution is "hernf"
what puzzles me is if 'n' should precede 'f', how is 'rfnn' valid?
am i missing something?
The question also implies there could be multiple solutions, how?

This is not about the order of letters in a word. rfnn is the last word in the sorted list of words, because its first letter r is higher in the underlying character sort order, than the letters h and e, that the other words begin with.

The order sequence hernf means, if you had any words beginning with n or f, those would come after the word rfnn in the sorted list of words.

For your last question, "there could be multiple solutions, how?", that's just if you don't have enough information. Example: if the input is the sorted list of words ["doe", "dog"]. From this list of words you can only deduce that 'e'<'g'; there is no information about 'd' and 'o'. So any of the 12 outputs "egdo", "egod", "doeg", "odeg", "edog", "eodg", "dego", "oegd", etc., would be possible. The only constraint is that 'e' comes before 'g' in your output.
